# expect script for getting output for multiple servers

Tags: shell-script, expect

I am trying to get output of IQN from multiple servers. I am getting the below error.

**Error output**

```
spawn /usr/bin/ssh VM2 | /usr/bin/cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
root@VM2's password:
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: -c: line 0: `| /usr/bin/cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi'
```

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="VM2 VM3 VM4 VM1"

read -p "Password: " PASSWORD

for HOST in $HOSTS
do
expect -c "
spawn cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
    expect {
    "*password:*" { send $PASSWORD\r;interact }
    }
    exit
    "
done
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where is `spawn` in your script? Make sure your code and your error output correspond

Comment: added `spawn` in the script but still not getting the output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't quite understand, what are you trying to achieve.

What I understood that you want to `cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi` on each server, right ?

But then why do you need to `interact` with each server?

I'll post solution for the first problem, where you login to each server, and `cat` file. I can edit solution, if you want to add `interact` as well.

So first of I decided to write most of the part of the script in `expect` itself and not pass it using `bash`. I think this way you'll get more errors.

So here is the bash script that is used as runner, it prompts for password, so that password is not printed or seen (it is not easy to do in `expect` directly)

```
#!/bin/bash 

expect_script="./connect_to_many_hosts_and_cat_files.exp"

[ ! -f $expect_script ] && echo expect_script does not exist && exit 1

echo "Please enter a password:"

read -s password

$expect_script $password
```

Now the `expect` script itself

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if {$argc != 1} {
   puts "please run expect script using bash script"
   puts "that prompts for password"
   exit
}

set password [lindex $argv 0]

# replace hosts names with your host names !!!
set hosts "host1 host2"

foreach host [ split $hosts " " ] {

    set number_of_password_prompts($host) 0

    puts "# "
    puts "# ssh $host"
    puts "# "

    spawn ssh $host
        expect {
            # here I put password check, just in case password is wrong
            # look a bit ugly, but better than nothing
            "Password:" {
                if { $number_of_password_prompts($host) == 0 } {
                    incr number_of_password_prompts($host)
                    puts "# "
                    puts "# Authenticating try $number_of_password_prompts($host)"
                    puts "# "
                    send "$password\r"
                    exp_continue
                } else {
                    puts "# "
                    puts "# Password is wrong"
                    puts "# "
                    exit
                }
            }
            # in case on host /bin/sh or /bin/bash
            "$ " {
                puts "# "
                puts "# cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi"
                puts "# "
                send "cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi \r"
                expect "$ "
            }
            # in case on host /bin/csh
            "% " {
                puts "# "
                puts "# cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi"
                puts "# "
                send "cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi \r"
                expect "% "
            }
            send "exit\r"
            expect eof
            close
        }
}
```

Last but not the least make sure you `chmod +x` both files. You can also run expect other way. And also make sure you put proper location of expect. For me it is `/usr/bin/expect`. For you could be anything else.

Also one important thing. For `expect` is important what prompt is out there on your servers. If it is `/bin/bash` you see I've put condition with `$` , if it is `/bin/csh` then you have to add condition with `%`.

It is very important for you to check how your `$PS1` or other prompt will look like after `ssh`. Script above won't work if your prompt is

```
    user@host:~>
```

For that to work, you have to include one more condition in `expect`

```
            "> " {
                puts "# "
                puts "# cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi"
                puts "# "
                send "cat /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi \r"
                expect "> "
            }
```

Please pay attention to that, I spend many days trying to figure out why things do not work.

Answer (score -1):

Use ansible for this case.

```
yum install ansible -y
vim /etc/ansible/hosts
[servers]
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3

ssh-keygen
```

Copy public key to destination server.
After this try to connect to server

```
ansible servers -m ping
```

In [ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/) you can find information about how to rule servers.

Comment: While I agree ansible is better suited for this, that is not an answer to the original question.